# How can I repeat these two lines of code 100+ times?

Tags: r, function, model

I'm still new to the programming world and looking for some guidance on a model I am building for individual animal growths over time. 
The goal for the code I'm working with is to
i) Generate random starting sizes of animals from a given distribution
ii) Give each of these individuals a starting growth rate from a given distribution
iii) Calculate new size of individual after 1 year
iv) Assign a new growth rate from above distribution
v) Calculate the new size of individual after another year.

So far I have the code below, and what I want to do is repeat the last two lines of code x amount of times without I having to physically run the code over and over.

```
# Generate starting lengths
lengths <- seq(from=4.4, to=5.4, by =0.1)

# Generate starting ks (growth rate)
ks <- seq(from=0.0358, to=0.0437, by =0.0001)

#Create individuals
create.inds <- function(id = NaN, length0=NaN, k1=NaN){
  inds <- data.frame(id=id, length0 = length0, k1=k1)
  inds
}

# Generate individuals
inds <- create.inds(id=1:n.initial,
        length=sample(lengths,100,replace=TRUE),    
         k1=sample(ks, 100, replace=TRUE))

# Calculate new lengths based on last and 2nd last columns and insert into next column
inds[,ncol(inds)+1] <- 326*(1-exp(-(inds[,ncol(inds)])))+
     (inds[,ncol(inds)-1]*exp(-(inds[,ncol(inds)])))

# Calculate new ks and insert into last column
inds[,ncol(inds)+1] <- sample(ks, 100, replace=TRUE)
```

Any and all assistance would be appreciated, also if you think there is a better way to write this please let me know.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a loop in R?

Comment: function `replicate()` may be what you are after...you can feed a user-defined-function into the `expr` parameter...here's a trivial use case to create two random samples of 10: `replicate(2, expr = rnrom(10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you are asking is a simple loop:

```
for (i in 1:100) { #replace 100 with the desired times you want this to excecute
 inds[,ncol(inds)+1] <- 326*(1-exp(-(inds[,ncol(inds)])))+
     (inds[,ncol(inds)-1]*exp(-(inds[,ncol(inds)])))

# Calculate new ks and insert into last column
inds[,ncol(inds)+1] <- sample(ks, 100, replace=TRUE) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so so much! I was trying to get this to work on my own but the r gods were not in my favour. Thanks for the speedy reply!!